# Secure code block execution in Oracle

Tags: oracle

For example I have a code:

```
BEGIN
    BEGIN
        -- First Part
        call_1_1();
        call_1_2();
        ...
        call_1_N();
    END;

    BEGIN
        -- Second Part
        call_2_1();
        call_2_2();
        ...
        call_2_M();
    END;
END;
```

This code placed at package and running in a job. Execution of this code (job) can be stopped from the outside by stopping the job. Interrupting could crach execution in the middle of the each block. And the question is how secure the execution of the blocks `First Part` or `Second Part` when someone interrupting execution from the outside.

Comment: What do you mean by 'secure'? Are you talking abput transaction control and atomicity - i.e. whether all the changes made will be rolled back?

Comment: By 'secure' I mean guarantee or safe execution of the whole code blocks in any cases. I understand that meaning of my question conflicts with Oracle transaction control concepts, but it's a question as is

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either all the transaction will complete or none of the transaction will complete.  Guaranteed.  You have to manage your transactions.  For example don't commit before the end of the "block" if you want the block to be in one transaction.